# How precise is the result after calculating a/b?

Tags: error-propagation, rounding-error, machine-precision

I have two numbers, $a$ and $b$, where the precision of $a$ is $n$ bits and the precision of $b$ is $m$ bits. How many bits of precision are preserved after calculating a/b on a normal computer nowadays?

I need the case where $n = 52$ and $m = (52-k)$.

Note: I need this to calculate $\lceil n/\ln(n!)\rceil$ and $\lfloor n/\ln(n!)\rfloor$. For a given $n$ I want to know how many bits of precision are necessary. The logarithm is calculated as the sum of the logarithms of the factors $1$ to $n$.

(This sounds like a trivial question, but I could not find anything related to this on google by searching for anything like "precision after division". Most of the questions are answered by "you loose precision because the number is stored in binary", which is not what I am looking for at all.)

Comment: When doing an arithmetic operation such as a division, the result is as precise as the number of bits given. If 10 bits are given, then the number is the closest 10-bit floating-point number to the algebraic result.

Comment: By the way, for $n>1$, $n/\ln(n!)$ never is an integer. So you only have to compute one quantity, and then add or subtract one to the other.

Comment: @Maxence1402 This would mean that giving $52$ bits of $a$ and $52-m$ bits of $b$, then the result would be, at least theoretically, accurate to exactly $104-m$ bits, do I understand that correctly? What do you mean by "computing one quantity"? What are you refering to as "quantity"?

Comment: I was talking about the bits returned, in the result. Say, I want to compute 1/3, then if I do this operation on 10 bits, I'll get 1,0101010101 × 2^-2, which is the closest number to 1/3 with 10 bits. The number of bits returned is independent from the number of bits given in argument (if needed, the machine adds zeros to prolong the calculation).
The "quantity" is either $\lceil n/\ln(n!)\rceil$ or $\lfloor n/\ln(n!)\rfloor$.

Comment: What you're looking for is how many bits of $\ln(n!)$ _you_ need to compute in order to get the numbers of bits of $n/\ln(n!)$ _you_ want. This is more a maths question than a computer science one.

Comment: Ah, now I know what you mean. Because it is never an integer I just need to calculate either of those and add or subtract 1 to get the other. Otherwise I'm talking about the error that occures when not knowing all the digits directly. For example, I have a precision of two bits for $a=b=1.0 * 2^1$ and I calculate $a / b = 1$, but it might be $10.0/10.1 = 1.100*2^-1$. The first significant digit is already wrong in this case.

Comment: I think it's only possible to give an interval where the answer may lie. Switching back to base $10$, for calculating $3/3$ it might be anything in the interval $(3/4, 4/3)$ without knowing any more digits of either $a$ or $b$. I could try calculating it up to a precision where the interval lies between two integers, which should be good enough I guess. I can calculate it, and if the interval does not lie between two neighbouring integers I increase prec.  There will always be such an intervall because the number is never an integer as you mentioned, would that seem like a reasonable approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128297/discussion-between-maxence1402-and-gamer2015).